# Pass data from tableView Cell to another view controller using delegate protocol

Tags: ios, swift

how to Pass data from tableViewCell to another view controller  and print data in label using delegate protocol swift 4

Comment: Here is your answer -> https://www.appcoda.com/swift-delegate/

Comment: You should at least try a little bit before posting a question. Or at least explain why you've already tried or what you need it for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply take a variable for value to be passed in your another `Viewcontroller`, then while pushing just pass the value.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    let vc = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AnotherVC") as! AnotherVC
    vc.variable = your value
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Why do you need to use protocols?

Comment: Explain more. why is it not useful?

Comment: For example we have 2 view controllers A then B(B view controller is pushed from A. ) A -> B. And we want to send data from B to A. Then we use protocols. But in your case we need to send data from A -> B, so here you can directly pass the value.

Answer (score 1):

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

//when you pass the view controller values to another VC

```
let vc = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AnotherVC") as! AnotherVC
vc.variableValue = your value
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

//You need to pass the cell values to another VC

```
 let vc = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AnotherVC") as! AnotherVC
 let variable = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)as! YourCell
 vc.varibleValue = cell.value
```

}

Don't Use protocols,Because you need to values from child to parent in this case  you use the Protocols. If you pass the Data from A to B just pass the Value is enough

Comment: i need to use protocls because its just test for me im new in ios

Comment: you need to pass the data between B to A?